# The number of functions on a finite set of numbers for which the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is an equality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let  $f$  be  a  function  from $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$ such  that  $$(\sum_{i=1}^{10} {{|f(i)|}\over {2^{i}}})^{2} = (\sum_{i=1}^{10}{|f(i)|}^{2})(\sum_{i=1}^{10}{{1}\over {4^{i}}}) $$

How many  such  $f$'s are  there  $?$

Now I  see $$(\sum_{i=1}^{10} {{|f(i)|}\over {2^{i}}})^{2}=(\sum_{i=1}^{10}{{|f(i)|}^{2}\over {4^{i}}})+2\cdot (\sum_{i=1\\, j\gt i}^{10}|f(i)|\cdot |f(j)|)$$ $$\le (\sum_{i=1}^{10}{|f(i)|}^{2})(\sum_{i=1}^{10}{{1}\over {4^{i}}}) + 2\cdot (\sum_{i=1\\, j\gt i}^{10}|f(i)|\cdot |f(j)|) $$ So  may  be  to  that  equality  hold  $$2(\sum_{i=1\\, j\gt i}^{10}|f(i)|\cdot |f(j)|)$$  should vanish. And  then  the  requirement  is  the  reverse  inequality.

Am  I  going  in  the  right  direction?

Comment: If you want to use multiplication dot, it's `\cdot`, not just . Also, the size of brackets can be made adjustable with left-right commands: `\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dots \right)` for $\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dots \right)$

Comment: @NormalHuman : Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work, as your apprximation is too weak.

**Hint:** Take a look at the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality and check when equality holds. $f$ is no different from a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$.

Comment: It  says ,  equality  holds  only  when  the  two  vectors  are linearly  dependant . So ,  that  means , the  vectors  $(f(1),f(2),....f(10) )$  and  $(2^{-1},2^{-2},........2^{-10})$  are  linearly  dependant i.e. $(f(1),f(2),....f(10) )$  is  a  scalar  multiple  of  $(2^{-1},2^{-2},........2^{-10})$ .  Then  we  can  get    uncountably infinite  such  $f$'s , same  in  number  as  cardinality  of  $\mathbb R$ .  Am  I  right $?$ @Dominik

Comment: Almost, you need to consider the vector that consits of the absolute values of $f$, since these numbers appear in the inequality.

Comment: Please  elaborate  your  second  comment a  little  more. Thanks for  your  help. @Dominik

Comment: Compare the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality with your inequality. Note that changing the sign of $f(i)$ doesn't change the value on either side of your inequality.

Comment: So  as  the  first  vector  I  should  take  $(|f(1)|,|f(2)|,....|f(10)|)$ . Is  that  what  you  meant $?$  @Dominik

Comment: Yes.  Applying the argumentation from your first comment to this vector yields the correct result.